# What is the place for input validation general rules in Domain Driven Design?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am developing a system following Domain Driven Design technics, my goal is to capture employees clock in and clock out. One requirement is that the system cannot permit two consecutive clocks for the same employee in a given time span. My question is where does this rule fits better, I don't see it pertaining to one entity but as a rule of some kind of process above domain entities. Advices?

Comment: Why wouldn't it belong to a single entity ? What is your domain model so far ?

Comment: @guillaume31, as I see this instance is very volatile, once the system accept the Clock and persiste it, I want to completly dispose it, I dont even want to keep it in memory anymore so why to put that logic into it? In fact I was thinking about this life cycle which is so brebe, a few seconds that I am wondering if this have to be an instance or some sort of write command. Is there some kind of pattern to such scenario in DDD world?

Comment: I don't get you. Why would the brevity of transactions have any impact on the "too close clockings not allowed" business rule ? Can't you store last clock-in time in the database ?

Comment: @guillaume31, I meant, I dont not want to keep information of past clocks time in a clock instance, that is why I think that this validation should be do it from outside by other process.

Comment: You don't have to store all past clock times, only last one for a given user. Now if you want more of a realtime system with a "throttler" daemon process that checks clockin/out frequency, I'm not sure DDD is a good fit there.

Comment: @guillaume31 I was thinking the same thing, I'll go with the path Victor Sergienko suggest but away from DDD for this system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The words "General rule" in a question are a sign of an under-specified requirements.

Answer a question: what does it mean "system cannot permit" - should it record the case? Decline to save the data? Send report to an employee's manager?

The domain model highly depends on what aspects of domain you model.

With the answer, you will get a more clear model, and the question will stop being too subjective for SO.

Depending on requirements, that could be:

- `employee`'s behaviour;
- `door`'s behaviour;
- `CorporateSecurity` service behaviour;
- an event handler in a DSL;
- a rule in a rules engine;
- something totally different.

**Edit**: if it's a matter of what data is allowed to be entered, then it's an input validation. There is one good approach described [in Martin Fowler's bliki](http://martinfowler.com/articles/replaceThrowWithNotification.html) - where an object can `validate()` itself and return a collection of validation errors.

Comment: By 'system cannot permit' I mean the application should discard such employees clocks, puting another way, it cannot be persisted and the user should be notified of this situation.

Comment: Excellent article, it seems to be my way to go in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a domain service that processes this. You can have your application layer fetch all clock-ins for the day and give it to the domain service. Alternatively, if IRepository lives in your domain layer, the domain-service can ask for the clock-ins.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this 'rule' is an actual invariant within your domain you probably should maintain the clock in and out information within your domain model? After all it sounds like the behaviour you're trying to capture.

As a side note, be careful not to let the databases influence the design of your domain model. It is helpful to be deliberate about whether or not you are applying a CRUD (create, read, update and delete) approach or trying to model an actual domain. If the later you need to take the time to discover the various bounded contexts which will help you model the domain more effectively.

I have a post you might find helpful, it has some loose definitions of the terms that could help, [Aggregate Root – How to Build One for CQRS and Event Sourcing](http://danielwhittaker.me/2014/11/15/aggregate-root-cqrs-event-sourcing/).

Comment: Instructive your post. In my case I dont want to mantain Clocks information in the client, that is why I see the Clock instance as very volatile, existing for just a few seconds. First I have to validate if I can create one Clock, if it is the case create a write command and execute it inmediatly, after that Im not instersted in that Clock instance anymore.